# get a Date format from a string

Tags: java, string, date

Android: I am saving a date in shared preferences as a String.

```
Date now = new Date(new Date().getTime());
savePreferences(key, "" + now);
```

I want to get back the date format from the string, how to do it?

Comment: do you mean that you want to restore the DateFormat from the string that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `java.util.Date` which is deprecated. You should use a [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) instead and then save it as a long using `getTimeInMillis()`.

This makes it much easier to work with. :-)

Comment: Actually java.util.Date is not entirely deprecated, only several of its methods. Nevertheless, you should avoid the java.util.Date/Calendar classes. Instead use Joda-Time or Java 8’s new java.time.* classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function.

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String startDate) throws ParseException
{
    String myFormatString = // Your stored date format like "dd-mm-yyyy"
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
    Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);
    return startingDate;
}
```

***Convert Milliseconds to date.***

```
long yourmilliseconds = 1119193190;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Comment: the getTime() returns the Date as a millisecond value. How can I get this millisecond value from the string?

Comment: your can parse your string milliseconds using Long.parseLong(string).

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly calling the `toString` method on the Date instance. Unfortunately, that class uses a poor format for rendering a string. One major problem is the use of 3-letter time zone codes that are neither standardized nor unique (there are duplicates such as EST and IST). That output should be avoided.

Indeed, all of the java.util.Date/Calendar classes should be avoided. Instead, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or Java 8’s new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Also, other answers suggest writing the number of milliseconds since an epoch. You can do so, but it is ambiguous. What epoch? There is more than one, though the Unix epoch is common and indeed is used by both java.util.Date and Joda-Time. What unit of time is that number? Old Unix style was to store number of seconds, while java.util.Date and Joda-Time use milliseconds, and the new Java 8 java.time* classes use nanoseconds.

The unambiguous way is to store a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, preferably in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (no time zone offset). Then in your user interface at runtime, convert as necessary to other formats and other time zones.

```java
String string = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```

To get…

```
string: 2013-12-27T07:15:00.395Z
```